# Universal message for exception class

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I have the following class for exceptions.

```
class MyException{
private:
    std::string message;
public:
    MyException(const std::string s): message(s){};
    void what() const{
         std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }
};
```

As you can see, I'm writing `message` to cout. I want `MyException` class to be able to write logs, for example. And at the same time I want to see some message in stdout.

What is the proper way to write exception class for such purposes?

Comment: It's your exception handler that should be doing the logging. Exception objects should not have much behaviour.

Comment: (1) As @NeilButterworth says do not have any unnecessary code in an exception class.  And (2) derive your class from std::exception or one of its derived exception classes.